# Сделать с помощью Stream

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-нибудь Iterator заменить Stream'ом. Если нет, то может можно как-нибудь укоротить код:

```
private boolean moveMan(Direction direction){
        int numberCollisionWithWalls=0;
    Iterator<Man> iterator = mans.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Man man = iterator.next();
        Position oneStep = direction.next(man.getPosition());
        GameObject gameObject = new GameObject(oneStep.getX(), oneStep.getY());
        if (walls.contains(gameObject)) {
            numberCollisionWithWalls++;
            continue;
        }
        if (badWalls.contains(gameObject)) {
            gameOver();
            return false;
        }
        Position twoStep = direction.next(oneStep);
        if (mans.contains(gameObject)&& walls.contains(new GameObject(twoStep.getX(), twoStep.getY()))) {
            gameOver();
            return false;
        }
        if (getTarget().equals(gameObject)) {
            iterator.remove();
            continue;
        }
        man.setPosition(oneStep);
    }
    if(numberCollisionWithWalls!=mans.size())
    {
        numbertStep++;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Стримы тут не нужны, у вас сплошные сайдэффекты в коде.

Comment: А может можно как-нибудь улучшить код?

Comment: Да он в принципе неплох.

Comment: два if'а, которые инициализируют gameOver - наверное можно и объединить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Ваша цель в повышении читаемости кода, то обратитесь к книге Роберта Мартина "Чистый код", а именно глава 3. Функции.

**Update:**

Для повышения читабельности рекомендуют стремиться к правилу одной операции. Например можно организовать код как:

```
private boolean moveMen(Direction direction) {
  Iterator<Man> iterator mans.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Man man = iterator.next();
    Position oneStep = direction.next(man.getPosition());
    Man manOnNextStep = (Man) new GameObject(oneStep.getX(), oneStep.getY());
    updateCollisionWithWalls(manOnNextStep);
    if(isGameOverForMan(manOnNextStep))
      return false;
    if (manOnNextStep.equals(getTarget()))
      iterator.remove();
    man.setPosition(oneStep);
  }
  return true;
}
```

И улучшать пока самому не начнёт нравиться итог.

Comment: Это скорей комментарий, чем ответ.

Comment: @Denis: Учту. Только начал обживаться на сайте, на момент ответа не мог ещё оставлять комментарии.

Comment: С вашим рейтингом, по-моему, уже можете себе это позволить :)